# Cakephp2 column comparison in where clause

Tags: comparison, where-clause, cakephp-2.5

I have to fetch data from attendances table `where status=1 and printed < allowed_prints`

i tried few things,current code is given below but not working

```
$attendances = $this->Attendance->find('all',array(
    'conditions'=>array(
                'Attendance.status'=>1,
                'Attendance.printed < Attendance.allowed_prints'
                )
));
```

above query returns the following error

Attendance does not have column `Attendance.printed < Attendance.allowed_prints`

Comment: What is the problem? Does it not give any results? Some results but wrong? Error message?

Comment: Attendance does not have column `Attendance.printed < Attendance.allowed_prints`